# can't print values when call structure values from main function

Tags: c, pointers, structure, function-pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

i have decleard a structure and allocate some memory too . using a function i update datas . i got error segmentation fault when i acssing data.

This is my code

In headerfile :

```
typedef struct
{
int member;
char *name;
}place;

void update(place **,int);
void display(place **,int);
```

in function

```
static memallocate(place **ptr,int viname,int index)
{

 ptr[index]=(place *)malloc(sizeof(place));
 ptr[index]->name=(char *)malloc(viname*sizeof(char *));

}

void update(place **ptr,int index)
{
 ---read string value "na" find the strlen as "pp"---
 memallocate(ptr,pp,index);
 ptr[index]->name=na;

}

void display(place **ptr,int index)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<index;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",ptr[i]->name);
    printf("%s\n",ptr[i]->country);
  }
}
```

in main file :

```
void main()
{
 int index=0;
 place *pla[5]={NULL};
 while(index<2)
 {
    update(&pla[index],index);
    index++;
 }
 display(pla,index);
}
```

my problem is i got segmentation fault when acessing function `display` and can't print datas ptr[0]->name,ptr[0]->country,ptr[1]->name,ptr[1]->country ..why this happen ? any memory fault . I got printing when i use printf after each updation .

Comment: Would help greatly if you posted something that compiles. Preferably the actual code you are getting a segfault from.

Answer (score 2):

I see two mayor issues here.

**1st**

Here

```
static void memallocate(place **ptr,int viname,int index)
{
  ptr[index]=(place *)malloc(sizeof(place));
  ptr[index]->name=(char *)malloc(viname*sizeof(char *));  
}
```

you allocate too much memory. It shall be

```
static void memallocate(place ** ptr, int viname, int index)
{
  ptr[index] = malloc(sizeof(place));
  ptr[index]->name = malloc(viname * sizeof(char));  
}
```

or even better:

```
static int memallocate(place ** ptr, size_t viname, size_t index)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == ptr)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    ptr[index] = malloc(sizeof *ptr[index]);
    if (NULL == ptr[index])
    {
      result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      ptr[index]->name = malloc(viname * sizeof *(ptr[index]->name));  
      if (NULL == ptr[index]->name)
      {
        result = -1;
        free(ptr[index]);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

**2nd**

Then here (assuming `na` to be a `char*` properly initilaised to reference a C-"string")

```
void update(place **ptr,int index)
{
  ---read string value "na" find the strlen as "pp"---
  memallocate(ptr,pp,index);
  ptr[index]->name=na;
}
```

you overwrite what you just assigned to `name`. To copy a C-"string" use `strcpy()`.

```
int update(place ** ptr, size_t index)
{
  ---read string value "na" find the strlen as "pp"---
  int result = memallocate(ptr, pp, index)
  if (-1 == result)
  {
    perror("memallocate() failed");
  }
  else
  { 
    strcpy(ptr[index]->name, na);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  size_t index = 0;
  place * pla[5] = {NULL};

  /* Loop over all array's elements. */
  while (index < sizeof pla/sizeof *pla)
  {
    update(pla, index);
    ++index;
  }

  ...
}
```

Notes:

- Always check the outcome of relevant function calls (here `malloc()`) and design your functions to be able to pass failures up to the caller.
- [Do not cast the result of `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` in C. It is not needed nor recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576)
- Prefer using `size_t` over `int` for memory sizes and indexes. `size_t` does not waste a bit for negative numbers and it is guaranteed to be large enough to address any arrays' element or represent any memory size. `sizeof` as well as `strlen()` return `size_t` not `int` for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your `update()`, you are passing a `place **` *of the current index* as argument.

However, you nevertheless pass `index` too and later in your `memallocate()`  allocate memory as if it was a pointer to the `place *[]`.

So it should help to remove the parameter `index` from `update()` and `memallocate()` and change the memory allocation to something like:

```
*ptr = (place *)malloc(sizeof(place));
*ptr->name = (char *)malloc(viname*sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: At least, I don't see how calling `update(&pla[index],index);` in `main()` and later allocating the memory to some offset of it can be correct. If it was to be done with passing the index, then the first argument should point to the array: `update(pla, index);`

Comment: You are correct, either pass the element directly or pass the array's root and the element's index. I fully missed the code for the OP's `main()` (had it been added later?). I assumed the code was called as per my updated answer. Please excuse, I take back my comment.